# Classify in tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/tensorflow/text-classification-using-tensorflow-js-an-example-of-detecting-offensive-language-in-browser-e2b94e3565ce) I want to load and use a model in tensorflowjs, and then use the classify method to classify an input.

I load and execute the model like this:

```
const model = await window.tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);

const threshold = 0.9;
const labelsToInclude = ["test1"];

model.load(threshold, labelsToInclude).then(model2 => {
    model2.classify(["test sentence"])
      .then(predictions => {
    console.log('prediction: ' + predictions);
    return true;
  })
});
```

But I am getting the error:

> TypeError: model2.classify is not a function at App.js:23

How can I use the classify method in tensorflowjs correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial uses a specific model ([toxicity](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity)). Its `load` and `classify` functions are not a feature of Tensorflow.js model itself but rather implemented by this specific model.

Check out the [API](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#Models) to see the supported functions for models in general. If you load a GraphModel, you want to use the [`model.predict`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.GraphModel.predict) (or [`execute`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.GraphModel.execute)) function to execute the model.

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```js
const model = await window.tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
const input = tf.tensor(/* ... */); // whatever a valid tensor looks like for your model
const predictions = model.predict([input]);
console.log('prediction: ' + predictions);
```